# I have an issue with "two quotes" in my project

Tags: html, css, quotes

Difficult to explain this, but there are 2 quotes on my navigation menu. I thought it was a little stain on my screen but it wasn´t. I have reviewed all my html document and css as well, but I can´t find the mistake. How can I remove this? Please refer the img attached at the bottom (the quotes are framed in red).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufj47.jpg)

This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Balance - Salud Mental</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="web.css">
    <!-- FONT POPPINS-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
    family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
    family=Poppins:wght@500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">"
    <!-- BACKGROUND HERO PATTERNS: TEMPLE COLORS: #FFFFFF #9ACD32-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navmain">
            <img src="img/bbsmf-removebg-preview.png" class="brand"/>
            <ul class="navmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Nuestra Mision</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">Nuestros Profesionales</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">Consultas y Citas</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blog</a>
                </li>
            </ul>    
        </nav>


And this is CSS code:

* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.container {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
color: #313335;

}

nav {
margin-top: -25px;

}

.navmain {
font-size: 17px;
justify-content: space-evenly;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
height: 100px;
background: white;

}

.brand {
width: 190px;
}

.navmain ul {
display: flex;
}

.navmain ul li {
padding: 30px;
list-style: none;
}

a {
color: #313335;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 18px;
}

#img1 {
width: 450px;
margin: 50px auto;
text-align: right;
margin-top: 10px;
}

body {
text-align: center;
background-color: #9acd32;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='152' 
height='152' viewBox='0 0 152 152'%3E%3Cg fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg id='temple' fill='%23ffffff' 
fill-opacity='0.22'%3E%3Cpath d='M152 150v2H0v-2h28v-8H8v-20H0v-2h8V80h42v20h20v42H30v8h90v-8H80v- 
42h20V80h42v40h8V30h-8v40h-42V50H80V8h40V0h2v8h20v20h8V0h2v150zm-2 0v-28h-8v20h-20v8h28zM82 
30v18h18V30H82zm20 18h20v20h18V30h-20V10H82v18h20v20zm0 2v18h18V50h-18zm20-22h18V10h-18v18zm-54 92v- 
18H50v18h18zm-20-18H28V82H10v38h20v20h38v-18H48v-20zm0-2V82H30v18h18zm-20 22H10v18h18v-18zm54 
0v18h38v-20h20V82h-18v20h-20v20H82zm18-20H82v18h18v-18zm2-2h18V82h-18v18zm20 40v-18h18v18h-18zM30 0h- 
2v8H8v20H0v2h8v40h42V50h20V8H30V0zm20 48h18V30H50v18zm18-20H48v20H28v20H10V30h20V10h38v18zM30 
50h18v18H30V50zm-2-40H10v18h18V10z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}


[enter image description here][1]

Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 1):

The quote you are getting is from this line -

```
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
    family=Poppins:wght@500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">" <-- Here
```

Remove it and you are good.